# Accurately measuring the runtime of a function in PHP and a similar one in C#

Tags: c#, php, image

Bit of a mixture of a question, I have got the following code in PHP which just rotates and image, and times how long it takes to rotate that image:

```
<?php
ini_set("memory_limit", -1);
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg("test.jpg");

$time_start = microtime(true);

$rotate = imagerotate($im,90,0);

$time_end = microtime(true);
$execution_time = "Took ". ($time_end - $time_start) * 1000 ." to generate image!";

$white = imagecolorallocate($im,255,255,255);
$font = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/ppa/images/fonts/Calibri Bold.ttf";

imagettftext($rotate,15,0,20,20,$white,$font,$execution_time);

header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
imagejpeg($rotate);

imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

If I run that code I get a number of around 404.000 displayed on my image, now I also have some code in C# which rotates the same image, **i'm afraid that the methods i'm using to time this though may not match and I could be getting false comparisons.**

Here is my C# code:

```
private void rotatec_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image image1 = pictureBox1.Image;
        if (image1 != null)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch s = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();

            image1.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipY);

            s.Stop();
            string text = "Time took: {0} ms" + s.ElapsedMilliseconds;

            pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = image1;
            image1.Save(@".\test.jpg");

            //Write to text file
            System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@".\timetook.txt");
            file.WriteLine(text);
            file.Close();
        } 
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please load an image first!");
        }
    }
```

**I'm afraid that the methods i'm using to time this though may not match and I could be getting false comparisons, is that so?...**

**------------------------------------------------------**

Updated my code, at the moment I get:

402.023 milliseconds from PHP (If i'm calculating it correctly)
148 milliseconds from C#

That seem realistic for rotating an image?

Comment: Could you please add an actual question?

Comment: @Samuel, made is nice and bold so you can see it

Comment: At first I would not round your php timestamp at the beginning but at the end. Then your C# code measures not only rotation and **storage** but also **setting** it as a background image which calls a cascade of events, which you are measuring too. What part are you trying to measure anyway?

Comment: Trying to measure the rotation, I will change that now

Comment: Just updated my code, does that look like I would get accurate comparisons?

Comment: Why are you trying to compare rotation time itself without opening and writing time? What is the purpose of this comparison?

Comment: I want to know if C# is going to be much faster than PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So. You are tring to measure operation rotation in different language and compare it. But first you have to make sure that your operation do the same job.

In your example it is not because input data and output data is completely different. It's internal represent of image resource. So, operations rotation do different things.

But if you include into your measure opening and writing file you could compare it.

P.S. do not forget that jpg has compression levels and set of different compression algorithms. Make sure that your output files are equal (at least similar).